# How can I get rid of a large space between cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a website, http://pigymunk.co.uk, and as you can see, the table has some fault where there's a a large gap between 2 cells. Can anyone help find that fault?

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="300" style="float:center" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <td><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/jackw.png" alt="JackW" style="align:"middle"/></td>
   </tr>
<tr>
   <td><a href="http://pigymunk.co.uk/?page_id=2" target="_self"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/About%20icon.png" alt="About" style=" align:"middle"/></a>    </td>
   <td><a href="http://pigymunk.co.uk/?page_id=76" target="_self"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/Blog%20icon.png" alt="Blog" style=" align:"middle"/></a></td>
```

Comment: You [shouldn't be using a table for that](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/) in the first place.

Comment: You should also use a validator (for both CSS and HTML) you have obvious, machine-detectable errors just in the snippit you've pasted here.

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/create-a-centred-horizontal-navigation/

Comment: Do not pay attention to the comment about not using tables. Both the comment and the link are biased and are a result of poor understanding  of programming. There is zero reasons not you use tables...

Comment: @RegisteredUser — Layout of a webpage has nothing to do with programming. It is markup and stylesheets.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I see you corrected one error, but your comment still doesn't make sense. Try reading it out loud.

Comment: @RegisteredUser No, you're still not making any sense, sorry.

Comment: @Mr Lister I know man, but I am working on it...

Comment: Oh, OK, as long as you realise it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean "You shouldn't be using tables for that"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colspan attribute of your first cell to span the other columns. Note the cell that has `<td colspan="4">`. Try this:

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="300" style="float:center" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <td colspan="4"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/jackw.png" alt="JackW" style=" align:"middle"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><a href="http://pigymunk.co.uk/?page_id=2" target="_self"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/About%20icon.png" alt="About" style=" align:"middle"/></a></td>
   <td><a href="http://pigymunk.co.uk/?page_id=76" target="_self"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/Blog%20icon.png" alt="Blog" style=" align:"middle"/></a></td>
   <td><a href="http://facebook.com/jackweatherilt" target="_self"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/Faceb%20icon.png" alt="Facebook" align:"middle"/></a></td>
   <td><a href="http://pigymunk.co.uk/distractions" target="_self"><img src="http://www.pigymunk.co.uk/distractions.png" alt="Demos" align:"middle"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ws6ZH/)**.

And just as a side note, you may want to look into updating your code and getting rid of deprecated attributes like `align="center"` and inline CSS among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: change the first `<td>` to `<td colspan="4">`.

Your table has one cell in the first row, four cells in the second row. This violates the HTML table model principles, so all bets are off. What happens in practice is what you see here: the first cell (the large image) is treated as belonging to the first column only.

This can be seen e.g. in Firefox Web Developer Extension, which has a function for drawing borders around all cells.

Comment: Actually, different amounts of cells in different rows are OK. This is in the standard. And most browsers handle this the same way, at least in standards mode, so you shouldn't worry too much about that.